# Deleting a node that has no siblings and also when its parent has no siblings in a binary search tree

Tags: c, algorithm, binary-search-tree

I have written this code for deleting a node that has no siblings and with a  parent that also has no siblings:

```
void DeleteSingles(struct BinaryTreeNode* root)
{
    struct BinaryTreeNode* parent,*child;
    if(!root) return;
    DeleteSingles(root->left);
    if((root->left==NULL)^(root->right==NULL))//checking from the root if it has a single child
   {
      parent=(root->left)?root->left:root->right;//let the parent be that node that has no siblings 
      if((parent->left==NULL)^(parent->right==NULL))//checking if that parent has a child with no sibilings 
      {
          child=(parent->left)?parent->left:parent->right;//save the target node for deletion
          if(child->left==NULL && child->right==NULL)//when the node to be deleted has no children
          {
              parent->left=parent->right=NULL;
          }
          else if((child->left!=NULL)&&(child->right!=NULL))//when the node to be deleted has 2 children
          {
             parent->left=child->left;
             parent->right=child->right;
          }
           free(child);
      }
   }
    DeleteSingles(root->right);
}
```

For example when I insert 5,4,3,2,1,6 to my BST this function is supposed to delete 1 and 2 because both of them have no siblings and also both of their parents have no siblings, I'm not sure if 6 satisfies this condition.

However this code only seem to work when the node to be deleted has no children, when I insert the values 5,4,3,2,1,-3,-2,6 it should delete 1,2.

Are my conditions here incorrect or am I missing something ?

I then tried the following after a suggestion from the comments :

```
void DeleteSingles(struct BinaryTreeNode** root)
{
    struct BinaryTreeNode* parent,*child;
    if(!(*root)) return;
    DeleteSingles(&((*root)->left));
    DeleteSingles(&((*root)->right));
    if((*root)->left==NULL ^ (*root)->right==NULL)
    {
        parent=((*root)->left == NULL)?(*root)->right:(*root)->left;
        if(parent->left==NULL ^ parent->right==NULL)
        {
            child=(parent->left==NULL)?parent->right:parent->left;
            if(child->left==NULL && child->right==NULL)
            {
                parent->left=parent->right=NULL;
            }
            else if(child->left!=NULL && child->right==NULL)
            {

                parent->left=child->left;
                parent->right=child->right;
            }
            printf("\nAbout to delete %d\n",child->data);
            free(child);
        }
    }
}
```

But still when my BST is 5,4,3,2,1,-3,-2,6 it deletes -2,-3,1,2 when -2 and -3 do not satisfy the condition.

Comment: In Binary Search Tree (BST) a node can only have one parent. So **Single parent** in your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: I meant that if a node has no siblings and its parent has no siblings then it should be deleted in my example 1 should be deleted because it has no siblings and its parent which is 2 also has no siblings.

Comment: I recommend explaining it in your question so that it won't be confusing.

Comment: In your first example, why only deleting 1, 2, not 1, 2, 3?

Comment: Because the parent of 3 which is 4 has a sibling which is 6.

Comment: 1) you should recurse into the children *before* handling the parent.2) this code does not leak, it *bleeds* 3) a pointer-to-pointer will solve all your problems.

Comment: Ah i see, i will try to write that code and see what will become of it.

Comment: I have changed my parameter to a double pointer and traversed left and right and then checked, but still this algorithm doesn't work when the node to be deleted has two children for example when i run it on 5,4,3,2,1,-3,-2,6 the code will delete -2,-3,1,2 but it shouldn't delete -3,-2.